Bazel: Why can GCC suddenly not find stdlib.h anymore?
My WORKSPACE file contains this code snippet:
new_local_repository(
    name = "boost",
    build_file = "//bazel/third_party:boost.BUILD",
    path = "C:/msys64/mingw64/include"
)

bazel/third_party:boost.BUILD looks like that:
cc_library(
    name = "boost",
    includes = ["."],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)

Building the main target, that depends on boost, works perfectly fine.

Now let's remove "include" from the path attribute in the WORKSPACE file and add it to the includes attribute in bazel/third_party:boost.BUILD:
WORKSPACE:
new_local_repository(
    name = "boost",
    build_file = "//bazel/third_party:boost.BUILD",
    path = "C:/msys64/mingw64"
)

bazel/third_party:boost.BUILD:
cc_library(
    name = "boost",
    includes = ["include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)

Building the main target now suddenly produces this error:
ERROR: C:/users/vschaerl/projects/testbazel/testbazel/src/BUILD:1:10: Compiling src/main.cpp failed: (Exit 1): g++ failed: error executing CppCompile command (from target //src:main) C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++ -MD -MF bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/_objs/main/main.d -frandom-seed=bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/_objs/main/main.o -iquote . -iquote ... (remaining 25 arguments skipped)
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:4097,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/string:54,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/streambuf:43,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:35,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/iterator:66,
                 from external/boost/include/boost/array.hpp:44,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/cstdlib:79:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
   79 | #include_next <stdlib.h>
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Target //src:main failed to build

Why? Shouln't it behave just the same? I only moved "include" from path to includes...
By the way, I'm on Windows and defined a custom MinGW toolchain for Bazel according to this tutorial: https://github.com/EhabHelaly/bazel_mingw_toolchain
And there are three stdlib.h files in C:\msys64\mingw64\include:

in C:\msys64\mingw64\include
in C:\msys64\mingw64\include\c++\13.2.0
in C:\msys64\mingw64\include\c++\13.2.0\tr1


Thanks a lot.

EDIT/ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
This is the compiler command line generated by Bazel before moving "include" from path to includes, when everything works fine (I separated the compiler options by lines for better readability):
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++
-MD
-MF bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/_objs/main/main.d
-frandom-seed=bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/_objs/main/main.o
-iquote .
-iquote bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin
-iquote external/boost
-iquote bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/external/boost
-iquote external/bazel_tools
-iquote bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools
-isystem external/boost
-isystem bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/external/boost
-c src/main.cpp
-o bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/_objs/main/main.o

This is the compiler command line after moving "include" from path to includes, which produces said error:
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++
-MD 
-MF bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/_objs/main/main.d
-frandom-seed=bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/_objs/main/main.o
-iquote .
-iquote bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin
-iquote external/boost
-iquote bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/external/boost
-iquote external/bazel_tools
-iquote bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools
-isystem external/boost/include
-isystem bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/include
-c src/main.cpp
-o bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/_objs/main/main.o

I think the problem lies in -iquote external/boost not changing. Before, external/boost points to C:\msys64\mingw64\include, which is the correct path, but after, it points to C:\msys64\mingw64, which is not correct. Why does Bazel not change the path in the -iquote compiler option?
EDIT 2:
echo | gcc -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only, which according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839946/18226035 shows the default GCC include directories, prints this:
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "D:/a/msys64/mingw64/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw64/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "D:/a/msys64/mingw64/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/backward
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include-fixed
End of search list.


My guess would be that having C:/msys64/mingw64/include on the include path twice interferes with #include_next

@AlanBirtles What do you mean by "having C:/msys64/mingw64/include on the include path twice"? In my understanding it's only once on the include path.

have you checked the compiler command line?

@AlanBirtles I did now, and added the compiler command lines to my question, under EDIT/ADDITIONAL INFORMATION. I would appreciate it if you could have a look at it.

What does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories print?

@AlanBirtles I just added it under EDIT 2

Any environment variables set https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304331/usr-include-c-8-cstdlib7515-fatal-error-stdlib-h-no-such-file-or-directo ? Precompiled headers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262928/error-compiling-opencv-fatal-error-stdlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory? Seems to be a common problem with mingw https://www.google.com/search?q=%2523include_next+%3Cstdlib.h%3E+site:stackoverflow.com

@AlanBirtles I'm on Windows. I have added build --action_env=PATH=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin to .bazelrc but that's not the problem since the error still occurs without that. I couldn't find any information on whether Bazel supports precompiled headers or if there's an option to disable them.

I notice the compiler command line generated by Bazel after moving include dir to includes is that the -isystem path has include dir appended at the end of the original -isystem path.
Before change
-isystem external/boost
-isystem bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/external/boost

After change
-isystem external/boost/include
-isystem bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/include

From the documentation, adding directories to the includes field would generate -isystem <path_to_package>/<include_entry> flags. This is consistent with the addition of include dir in the includes. However, it doesn't explain that why <path_to_package> remains unchanged. My guess is that <path_to_package> is configured elsewhere. To generate similar g++ command that worked, I don't think you need to add include in includes while also keeping path = "C:/msys64/mingw64" updated because it doesn't affect the generated g++ command
WORKSPACE:
new_local_repository(
    name = "boost",
    build_file = "//bazel/third_party:boost.BUILD",
    path = "C:/msys64/mingw64"
)

bazel/third_party:boost.BUILD:
cc_library(
    name = "boost",
    includes = ["."],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)


Your approach works, the project builds successfully. But the reasons for that remain a secret to me. The generated command line is the same as the one of the original setup. But of course external/boost now points to C:/msys64/mingw64 instead of C:/msys64/mingw64/include. Yet mysteriously it still works...

@VincentSchaerl From the documentation, path in new_local_repository  is simply the Bazel repository path in the filesystem. My guess on why the compile works is because it doesn't interfere with the process to generate g++ command
